# Reading numbers from the user until negative number is given, returning highest,lowest,range and number count?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, scanf, eof

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
  int a,count,highest,lowest,range;
  for(count=0;scanf("%d",&a) >= 0;count++){
    if(count == 0){
      highest = a;
      lowest = a;
    }
    if(a > highest){
      highest = a;

    }
    if(a < lowest){
      lowest = a ;
    }

  }
  range = highest - lowest;
  printf("%d\n %d\n %d\n %d\n",count,highest,lowest,range);
  return 0;
}
```

the problem is this program does not stop until I press CTRL D however I want it to stop when I enter negative number as you can see in `scanf("%d",&a) >= 0;` How can I solve this?

Comment: Please check the manual for `scanf` and see what the return value means. Negative return value is not related to a negative number entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the condition in the for loop the following way

```
for ( count = 0; scanf("%d",&a) == 1 && a >= 0; count++ ){
//...
```

Also it is better to combine all if statement in a group of if-else statements like

```
if ( count == 0 ){
  highest = a;
  lowest = a;
}
else if( a > highest ){
  highest = a;
}
else if(a < lowest){
  lowest = a ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`scanf()` function in C returns total number of Inputs Scanned successfully or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned. So in your case `scanf("%d",&a)` returns the value `1` even when you enter a negative number. Hence the `for` loop in your code will not terminate until you press **CTRL D**.

Answer (score 1):

this `scanf("%d",&a) >= 0` doesn't check `a>=0` this check `scanf` returned, which is about success of taking data and number of inputs taken.

```
int main(void) {
  int a,count,highest,lowest,range;
 scanf("%d",&a);
 for(count=0;a>= 0;count++){
    if(count == 0){
      highest = a;
      lowest = a;
    }
    if(a > highest){
      highest = a;

    }
    if(a < lowest){
      lowest = a ;
    }
   scanf("%d",&a);
  }
  range = highest - lowest;
  printf("%d\n %d\n %d\n %d\n",count,highest,lowest,range);
  return 0;
}
```